# program stalls immediately after beforeclass with log4j and springframework

Tags: java, spring, testing, annotations, log4j

test file's output stalls after closing the @beforeclass. It does not run @Before.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/spring-tests.xml"})
public class SomeMapperTest{

private static Logger logger;

   @BeforeClass
   public static void setupLog4j(){
   final String LOG4J_FILE = "test-log4j.properties";
   URL log4jFile = someMapperTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource(LOG4J_FILE);
   PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jFile);

   logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeMapperTest.class);
   logger.info("SomeMapperTest Logger initialized successfully!");
}
   @Autowired
   SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession;
   @Autowired
   SomeMapper someMapper;
   @Before
   public void setupclass()
   {
      /doesn't make it here
      someMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(SomeMapper.class);
   }//...
```

commenting out the two annotations above the class cause it to run but it won't get the sqlSession. Is there anything obious that I'm missing? Thank you!

EDIT:
here's the test-log4j.properties file

```
log4j.logger.dir=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.com.sun=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG,stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%c:%L) - %m%n

log4j.additivity.com.eds=false
```

Comment: do all your set up in @before only

Comment: I tried it just now and @before still doesn't run. I appreciate the help!